# Add a new string in between existing string

Tags: java

I have read the content of HTML into string, now I need to add a new attribute inside the body tag, I was thinking of using StringBuilder for this. But I am unable to frame the logic. Any help would be really appreciated.

Existing HTML

```
<body class="temporaryrevision">
```

HTML that I want to create

`<body class="temporaryrevision" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">`

Comment: Use an appropriate object model, make your life easier, something like [jsoup](http://jsoup.org/) for example...

Comment: Do you have to do this in Java ? do you have to actually set the bgcolor on the HTML tag (no use of a CSS file) ? Can you provide a little bit more context to your problem to help us answer it ?

Comment: Yes I am currently trying to do this in java, I want to append a new attribute in HTML body tag, I don't want it in CSS.

Comment: what about using jquery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
String htmlString="<html>...<body class="temporaryrevision">..</body>...</html>";  
String[] tempData=htmlString.split("<body class=/"temporaryrevision/""); 
String data = tempData[0]+"bgcolor=/"#FFFFFF/""+tempData[1];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use jQUery for this:

```
$( ".temporaryrevision" ).attr( "bgcolor", "#FFFFFF" );
```

Answer (score 0):

Ill suggets a way that will be generic:

Use a XML parser for the same.

1. Load the file into java and pass it to and instance of XML Parser(SAXParser or something like that)
2. Traverse the parsed Object tree to your required element tag name. in this example HTML
3. use Library method to add attribute to the element.
4. convert the object back to xml format(Basic HTML).
5. Write and replace the file contents with your updated content.

This way is complex but will be generic to all ur such needs..